# How to remove annotations in pdf in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

My original goal was to remove the extensive white margins on my PDF pages.

Then I found this purpose can be achieved by scaling the page using the code below, but annotations are not scaled.

```
import PyPDF2

# This works fine
with open('old.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_obj:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_obj)
    out = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    for page in pdf.pages:
        page.scale(2, 2)
        out.addPage(page)
    with open('new.pdf', 'wb') as f: 
        out.write(f)

# This attempts to remove annotations
with open('old.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_obj:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_obj)
    page = pdf.pages[2]
    print(page['/Annots'], '\n\n\n\n')
    page.Annots = []
    print(page['/Annots'])
```

Is there a way to remove annotations? Or any suggestion that can help me to get rid of the white margin.

Comment: According to [PyPDF2 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html) the `PdfFileWriter` has a `removeLinks()` method that "removes links and annotations." Can you use that?

Comment: This works for me, thanks! @TrevorReid

Comment: Great.  Glad it helped @n33. I submitted that as an answer based on your success and a little more testing of my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `PdfFileWriter.removeLinks()` removes links and annotations. So, if you are okay with losing both you can add `out.removeLinks()` in your first block of code, the one that's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone using PyPDF2-3.0.1,this will work fine for you

```
import PyPDF2

with open('input.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_obj:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_obj)
    out = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    for page in pdf.pages:
        if page.annotations:
            page.annotations.clear()
        out.add_page(page)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as f: 
    out.write(f)
```